# How to use token which contains XML strings in a website SetParameters.xml file on VSTS?

Tags: token, webdeploy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, winrm

On VSTS, I use the "Replace Tokens" task to replace tokens in SetParameters.xml file with the VSTS variables. But I have variables which contains a XML string.
For example, with a VSTS variable which contains:

```
<string>aaa</string><string>bbb</string><string>ccc</string>
```

I got in the SetParameters.xml:

<`setParameter name="FolderTreeStructureRootFullControl"
               value="<string>aaa</string><string>bbb</string><string>ccc</string>" />`

After, when I deploy the website with the "WinRM - IIS Web App Deployment" task, I have this error :

```
System.Exception: Error: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character.
```

Is there a way to fix this error without replace all '<' and '>' characters by `&lt;` and `&gt;` escape strings ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t, I recommend that you can encode the value to base64 and decoding the value in the code.